# Find an equation for the straight line tangent to this curve at the given point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As you can check, the point $(1,\ln(2))$ lies on the curve
$xe^y+7y−2x=7\ln(2).$

Find an equation for the straight line tangent to this curve at the given point.
Your answer should be an equation involving x and/or y.
Use ln() for the natural logarithm.

Tried to fin a function y=... but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a point on the curve: $(x_0, y_0) = (1, \ln 2)$. You need to determine the "slope" $m$ of the tangent line at $x = 1$. To find that slope, you need to find derivative by implicit differentiation: $$\dfrac{2 - e^y}{xe^y + 7}$$ then evaluate at $x = 1, y = \ln 2$, and set $f'(1, \ln 2) = m = 0$.

Then you'll have both a point on the line, and slope, and using point-slope form for an equation, you're good to go:

$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$

$$y - \ln 2 = 0(x - 1) = 0 \iff y = \ln 2$$ And you've got your line, parallel to the x-axis.

Comment: Note that slope is zero, since the numerator of d/dx at $(1, \ln 2)$ is $2 - e^{\ln 2} = 2 - 2 = 0$, and the denominator is *nonzero* that point.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but the derivative of $xe^y + 7y -2x$ is *not* $(2 - e^y)(xe^y + 7)^{-1}$.  Not to be overly shamelessly self-promoting, but I believe the correct form of these derivatives is given in my answer to this question.  Cheers! (Ulp!), Bob Lewis

Answer (score 1):

The curve, if I read it right, is

$xe^y + 7y -2x = 7 \ln 2, \tag{1}$

and sure enough, taking $(x, y) = (1, \ln 2)$ provides a point on this curve.

We differentiate (1) implicitly, yielding

$e^y + xy'e^y + 7y' - 2 = 0, \tag{2}$

and solve the resulting equation for $y'$; it's linear in $y'$, so that helps:

$e^y + y'(xe^y + 7) = 2, \tag{3}$

so

$y' = (2 - e^y)(xe^y + 7)^{-1}. \tag{4}$

Plugging in $(x, y) = (1, \ln 2)$ gives

$y' = (2 - 2)(2 + 7) = 0 \tag{5}$

at the point $(1, \ln 2)$.

So using the general form $(y - y_0) = m(x - x_0)$ for the tangent line, as suggested by AmWhy in his answer, gives

$y - \ln 2 = 0; \tag{5}$

so the tangent line is horizontal at the point $(1, \ln 2)$!

Hope this helps!  Cheers, and as always,

***Fiat Lux***